# How to combine related data

Tags: json, go

I need some theoretical/practical help in code organization.

I have such table in `PostgreSQL` database. The table shows the relationship between organizations.

```
| ORGANIZATION_ID | ORGANIZATION_NAME | PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID | ORGANIZATION_RANG | TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID | TREE_ORGANIZATION_ NAME |
|-----------------|-------------------|------------------------|-------------------|----------------------|-------------------------|
| 1               | Google            |                        | 1                 | \1                   | \Google                 |
| 2               | Nest              | 1                      | 2                 | \1\2                 | \Google\Nest            |
| 3               | Verily            | 1                      | 2                 | \1\3                 | \Google\Verily          |
| 4               | Calico            |                        | 1                 | \4                   | \Calico                 |
| 5               | ATAP              | 4                      | 2                 | \4\5                 | \Calico\ATAP            |
```

In my Go application I create `struct` for this table then make SQL query.

```
type Organization struct {
    ID int `json:"organization_id"`
    Name string `json:"organization_name"`
    Rang int `json:"organization_rang"`
    Children []Organization `json:"children"`
}

var GetOrganizations = func(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    rows,err := db.Query("select * from ORG")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    var organizations []Organization

    for rows.Next() {
        var organization Organization

        err = rows.Scan(&organization.ID, &organization.Name, &organization.Rang)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        organizations = append(organizations, organization)
    }

    utils.Response(responseWriter, http.StatusOK, organizations)
}
```

I need to make such response. What would you advise to reorganize in my current code?

```
[
    {
        "organization_id": 1,
        "organization_name": "Google",
        "organization_rang": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "organization_id": 2,
                "organization_name": "Nest",
                "organization_rang": 2,
                "children": null
            },
            {
                "organization_id": 3,
                "organization_name": "Verily",
                "organization_rang": 2,
                "children": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "organization_id": 4,
        "organization_name": "Calico",
        "organization_rang": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "organization_id": 2,
                "organization_name": "Nest",
                "organization_rang": 2,
                "children": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**EDIT**:

@antham for example I add new record called `Telsa`. As you can see it's parent is `Nest` object.

```
| ORGANIZATION_ID | ORGANIZATION_NAME | PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID | ORGANIZATION_RANG | TREE_ORGANIZATION_ID | TREE_ORGANIZATION_ NAME |
|-----------------|-------------------|------------------------|-------------------|----------------------|-------------------------|
| 1               | Google            |                        | 1                 | \1                   | \Google                 |
| 2               | Nest              | 1                      | 2                 | \1\2                 | \Google\Nest            |
| 3               | Verily            | 1                      | 2                 | \1\3                 | \Google\Verily          |
| 4               | Calico            |                        | 1                 | \4                   | \Calico                 |
| 5               | ATAP              | 4                      | 2                 | \4\5                 | \Calico\ATAP            |
| 6               | Tesla             | 2                      | 3                 | \1\2\6               | \Google\Nest\Tesla      |
```

Result of your code:

```
[
    {
        "organization_id": 1,
        "organization_name": "Google",
        "organization_rang": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "organization_id": 3,
                "organization_name": "Verily",
                "organization_rang": 2,
                "children": null
            },
            {
                "organization_id": 2,
                "organization_name": "Nest",
                "organization_rang": 2,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "organization_id": 6,
                        "organization_name": "Tesla",
                        "organization_rang": 3,
                        "children": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "organization_id": 2,
        "organization_name": "Nest",
        "organization_rang": 2,
        "children": [
            {
                "organization_id": 6,
                "organization_name": "Tesla",
                "organization_rang": 3,
                "children": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "organization_id": 4,
        "organization_name": "Calico",
        "organization_rang": 1,
        "children": [
            {
                "organization_id": 5,
                "organization_name": "ATAP",
                "organization_rang": 2,
                "children": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: How does `select * ...` from a table with 6 columns scan into 3 fields without error?

Comment: http://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html if you can use 3rd lib, you can keep your struct pretty much the same.

Comment: @mkopriva hello! You are right. SQL query must be `select * ORGANIZATION_ID, ORGANIZATION_NAME, ORGANIZATION_RANG from ORG`. The current code with return me 5 record and in final response I have array with 5 object which is not what I want. How would you implement nesting as in my case?

Comment: @nvcnvn hello! How exactly this ORM could help me? Can you show a practical example for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand properly what you want to do, here you have an unoptimized example, it's done with sqlite but it will work the same with postgres :

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "sort"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

type Organization struct {
    ID       int             `json:"organization_id"`
    Name     string          `json:"organization_name"`
    Rang     int             `json:"organization_rang"`
    Children []*Organization `json:"children"`
}

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./database")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query("select ORGANIZATION_ID,ORGANIZATION_NAME,ORGANIZATION_RANG,PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID from ORG")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    orgs := map[int]*Organization{}

    for rows.Next() {
        organization := &Organization{}
        var parentID sql.NullInt64

        if err = rows.Scan(&organization.ID, &organization.Name, &organization.Rang, &parentID); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if parentID.Valid {
            if parentOrg, ok := orgs[int(parentID.Int64)]; ok {
                parentOrg.Children = append(parentOrg.Children, organization)
            } else {
                orgs[int(parentID.Int64)] = &Organization{ID: int(parentID.Int64)}
                orgs[int(parentID.Int64)].Children = append(orgs[int(parentID.Int64)].Children, organization)
            }
        }

        if _, ok := orgs[organization.ID]; ok {
            orgs[organization.ID].Name = organization.Name
            orgs[organization.ID].Rang = organization.Rang
            continue
        }

        orgs[organization.ID] = organization
    }

    IDs := []int{}
    for k := range orgs {
        IDs = append(IDs, k)
    }
    sort.Ints(IDs)

    organizations := []Organization{}
    for _, ID := range IDs {
        if len(orgs[ID].Children) > 0 && orgs[ID].Rang == 1 {
            organizations = append(organizations, *orgs[ID])
        }
    }

    content, err := json.MarshalIndent(organizations, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(content))
}
```

I get this :

```
[
  {
    "organization_id": 1,
    "organization_name": "Google",
    "organization_rang": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "organization_id": 2,
        "organization_name": "Nest",
        "organization_rang": 2,
        "children": null
      },
      {
        "organization_id": 3,
        "organization_name": "Verily",
        "organization_rang": 2,
        "children": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "organization_id": 4,
    "organization_name": "Calico",
    "organization_rang": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "organization_id": 5,
        "organization_name": "ATAP",
        "organization_rang": 2,
        "children": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you. In fact I need to show response only with top level organizations with nersed children. There must be array with only `Google` and `Calico` objects. Every object has childer. Do you understand me? What I need to change in your code for this task? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It seems like your code works only for constant nesting level (rang). Can you add some children to `Nest` object just for the test? In my case nesting level (rang) is not constant. Objects that have children are duplicated in the main array. For example if you will add some childen to `Nest` object, you will notice that this object in duplicated in the main array. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: If you want to know if it works for several level of children, the answer is yes, try and you will see. Here it's a simple answer based on what I understood from what you've dumped so you have to adapt this script to fit exactly your need.

Comment: Can you check my post again please? I add information about result of your last code. Unfortunatly it don't work correctly.

Comment: So what is supposed to do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190089/discussion-between-antham-and-nurzhan-nogerbek).